# Need tooltip in customization

Tags: javascript, highcharts

If I have any least value at the bottom of the chart, it is not showing properly.Which means the least value is under 1% of the highest value, it is not showing in the chart.

If I convert that value more than 1% of the higher value, it is showing. But I need to show the actual value rather than the converted one on tooltip.

Please let me know if we have any ways to achieve this[image: ![rt]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIOco.png)

Comment: can you explain more with code snippet :)

Comment: Can you provide code ?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the tooltip content using `tooltip.formatter`. Save the correct value in point object property (realValue in the example) and then use it in tooltip.formatter. Check demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      var text = 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
        '</b> is <b>';

      if (this.point.realValue) {
        text += this.point.realValue + '</b>'
      } else {
        text += this.y + '</b>'
      }

      return text;
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      43934,
      52503,
      {
        realValue: 10000,
        y: 50000,
        color: 'red'
      },
      69658,
      97031,
      119931,
      137133,
      154175
    ]
  }],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pyt4w819/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter